# IC pins too small for my breadboard

Tags: integrated-circuit, wiring, breadboard

I recently bought some IC's with 8 and 16 pins. 
I was used to work with bigger ones, so now I cant test them in the breadboard without soldering an individual wire to each pin (which would probably destroy the IC). 
I thought about sockets, but it doesn't make the distance between pins bigger.

Is there any device I can use to connect the small IC's to the breadboard?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Google ZIF smt to dip adapter

Comment: Apart from the 'ZIF SMT to DIP' adapter @EugeneSh. mentions, there are also things called 'break-out boards' which are bits of PCB with breadboard-sized pins on one side, and a place to solder your IC on the other side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your IC does not come in a DIP package, you can use a break-out board like this [one (Adafruit)](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1207) and some pin headers and solder your SOIC-16 or TSSOP-16 package onto it to use it in a breadboard. This of course assumes the package you have bought is a 16 pin package - there are other versions of the breakout board available on the internet as well.

[image]

(Image courtesy of Adafruit.com)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you bought parts in a surface mount package, such as SOIC.

For use with the common plastic breadboard, you need to use standard DIP package parts, where the pins are on 0.1" centers, and are formed to go through a PC board.

Many components are available in both surface mount and through-hole packages - you must take care to select the appropriate package for your use.